# Get number of times character is present next to each other in c#

Tags: c#, char

I'm trying to get true or false whether a character is repeating in a sequence. E.g `::NWAVE12345`
If this occurs, it should return true, because we have `::`. However, if we have only one `:` returns false. All I want is to check if that specific character appears more than one time in a sequence.

Any ideas?

```
var countColon = sensor.Count(c => c == ':');
```

This counts the times then colon exists, which doesn`t help me.

Comment: string.Contains("::"); ?

Comment: Would ":NWAVE12345:" be something you want to get or something you want to discard? Is "::" the only option or can it appear multiple times without being next to each other?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you could use `string.Contains("::");` to see if it contains `::`, because if it has more then two, it still returns `true`.

One more option is to use regex: `Regex.Match(str, ":{2,}").Success`

Pattern explanation: `:{2,}` - match colon 2 or more times.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WWeXOD/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

```
void Main()
{

    string mySentence = "myy senttence";
    IsRepeating(mySentence, 't'); //return True
    IsRepeating(mySentence, 'y'); //return True
    IsRepeating(mySentence, 'e'); //return False
}

public bool IsRepeating(string sequence, char character)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(sequence, character + "{2,}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if given char is found more than 1 time in string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">String to search into</param>
/// <param name="c">Char to search for</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool ExistsManyTimes(string str, char c)
{
    return str.Count(x => x == c) > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. This will count the sequences and return true case finds any of them

```
    bool checkSequence(char cr, string word)
    {
        char previous = cr;
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (char letter in word)
        {
            if (previous == letter && letter == cr && i > 0)
                count++;
            previous = letter;
            i++;
        }
        return count > 0;
    }
```